# Two linux programs running simultaneously and keypress capturing

Tags: c, linux

I have an OpenVG digital signage application running on Raspberry Pi (linux). Unfortunately, making it display a full-screen .jpg background in a loop slows down things a lot.

So instead I went for a transparent background and my OpenVG program running on layer 1. Then, I also start FBI (a shell program that displays images in framebuffer). That way I have the same visual effect but also a huge speed-up in OpenVG program working like an overlay which is very important in my case. To start both programs simultaneously I use this command:

```
fbi -noverbose bg.jpg | ./digital-signage
```

(-noverbose argument makes fbi display no UI, just a fullscreen image)

The problem is, I would like to be able to capture and process keypresses in my OpenVG application. The code for it looks like this:

```
void changemode(int dir) {
    static struct termios oldt, newt;

    if (dir == 1) {
        tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
        newt = oldt;
        newt.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
        tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);
    } else {
        tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
    }   
}

int kbhit(void) {
    struct timeval tv;
    fd_set rdfs;

    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    FD_ZERO(&rdfs);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &rdfs);

    select(STDIN_FILENO+1, &rdfs, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    return FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &rdfs);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char key = 0;

    changemode(1);
    while (!kbhit()) {
        // do the rendering here until a key is pressed
    }
    key = getchar();
    changemode(0);
    finish(); 

    printf("%c", key);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the program will loop until a keypress is detected, then it echoes the key and exits. It works fine when I only run the OpenVG application:

```
./digital-signage
```

But when I do this...

```
fbi -noverbose bg.jpg | ./digital-signage
```

The key is always wrong because fbi seems to catch the input (and it does properly because it reacts to keyboard shortcuts). **The program exits but detects incorrect key.**

My problem is that I do not need fbi to react to anything. I need my OpenVG application to handle keypress properly. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: what's wrong with `./digital-signage | fbi -noverbose bg.jpg`?

Comment: ioctl VT_GETSTATE: inappropriate ioctl for device (not a linux console?)
OpenVG application starts but fbi does not.

Comment: how about `fbi -noverbose bg.jpg &` and then `./digital-signage`?

Comment: After the first command the screen went blank and I could not do anything but reboot my Pi.